# C# get all parameters as a single string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameters

Say I have this url:

```
url/myurl?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3&param4=4
```

Is it possible to get the fill string `"param1=1&param2=2&param3=3&param4=4"` so I can just pass that around?

```
string data = *GetAllParams()*
```

I am aware that `Request.QueryString` will return all parameters, but I would rather not loop through all parameters and add them to a string if I can avoid it.

Comment: if you do not want to use the `uri.Query` property then you can still use the split() function along with the `string.Join()` method but that's a long way to do it.. which does not involve any loops what so ever.. also a simple google search would have yielded many similar results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class and use [`Uri.Query`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query(v=vs.110).aspx) property to get your parameters: like:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/myurl?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3&param4=4");
Console.WriteLine(uri.Query);
```